# How can I make shift+spacebar page up in Vim?

Tags: vim, paging, configuration-files

I have an entry in my .vimrc which makes it page down the viewport when I hit the spacebar. It looks like this:

```
map <Space> <PageDown>
```

I want to create another key mapping which pages the viewport up when holding shift and hitting the spacebar. I have tried the following entries:

```
map <Shift><Space> <PageUp>
map <S-Space> <PageUp>
```

Neither work. Anybody know how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You cannot. CMS's solution will work for gVim, but not in vim because terminals cannot distinguish between <Space> and <S-Space> because curses sees them the same. It might be possible in the future if vim gains libtermkey support and your terminal supports the proper <CSI> sequences (xterm does if properly configured; nothing else does yet).

Comment: Might want to edit your answer...cannot distinguish between what?  I assume you mean the terminal cannot distinguish between CTRL-SPACE and simple SPACE by itself.

Comment: Oops, yes, it was eating everything between less than and greater than signs. Fixed.

Comment: Can you link something that explains what "properly configured" means?

Comment: @Unode  Configuring XTerm to send a different escape sequence than the single character 0x20 when the space bar is pressed while the shift key is depressed.  This is done with the "translations" resource.

Comment: It can be work around using the capability of your terminal emulator to send something else upon hitting `shift`+`space`. See @BijouTrouvaille's answer for iTerm2, or [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88592/108579) for (u)rxvt (and xterm in a comment).

Comment: Probably relevant iTerm issue: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3519

also mentioned this issue at https://github.com/zeit/hyper/issues/2602#issuecomment-403312098

Answer (score 19):

If you are using vim inside iTerm2 you can map shift-space to ctrl+U by sending the hex key 15. Here's a screen shot:

[image]

To look up a hex code for a ctrl+letter combination, for example ctrl+u, you can do the following:

- In vim enter the insert mode
- Hit ctrl+v then ctrl+u then ctrl+c then ga
- various numerical representations will print at the bottom

You can apply this idea to other terminal emulators that support key mapping.

Comment: Do this all the time. For example, I have mapped `C-i`, `C-m`, `C-,`, and `C-.` to the `F1` to `F4` hex codes. The function keys are great for this if you otherwise never use them.

Comment: Fantastic workaround but I'd suggest use something other than `<C-u>` as that key is currently used to clear the input line.

Comment: Clarification: `ga` is a mapping for `:as[cii]`, in case you have `ga` already mapped elsewhere.

Answer (score 8):

Use this:

```
map <Space> ^D   " Pagedown when press Space
map <S-Space> ^U " Page Up when press Shift Space
```

To get the ^D and ^U symbol correctly just press Control-V Control-D, and Control-V Control-U

Comment: When doing this, it pages down when using both Space and Shift Space... I have tried this in Debian Linux and OS X. I am running VIM 7.0 and VIM 7.2 respectively

Comment: Doesn't work in my Arch box. Probably works only on OSX?

Answer (score 3):

For OSX:

```
nnoremap <Space> <C-d>
nnoremap <S-Space> <C-u>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320750/124200), I got the mapping done by:

- Using a terminal that supports key mapping
- Mapping <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to a sequence of characters that can be distinguished from <kbd>Space</kbd> by Vim, but still has a net effect of writting a space when you input text.

#### How-to:

1. **Choose one of those terminals that are capable of key mapping.**
   For example, Alacritty, xterm, urxvt, or Kitty.
2. **Choose the character sequence to which <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will be mapped.**
   <kbd>SOME_KEY</kbd>,<kbd>Backspace</kbd>,<kbd>Space</kbd> should do the trick, where <kbd>SOME_KEY</kbd>:

   - writes a character that can be canceled out by a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> when inputting text, e.g. a printable character or a tab.
   - is also a key you rarely use in Vim normal mode and/or visual mode (depending on which mode you want to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in). If it has already been binded to some heavily-used command, you may experience some lag (see `:h timeout` for details) every time you use the command.

   I am using <kbd>\</kbd> as <kbd>SOME_KEY</kbd> (<kbd>`</kbd> may also be a good option).
3. **Mapping in the terminal**
   I'm using [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty), so here is an example of mapping <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to the character sequence in Alacritty. In the config file add the following line under the "key_bindings" item: `- { key: Space, mods: Shift, chars: "\x5c\x08 " }`.

   To confirm the mapping works, run `showkey -a` in the terminal and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, then the character sequence should be output. For the example above, the output is:

   ```
    \^H      92 0134 0x5c  
              8 0010 0x08  
             32 0040 0x20
   ```
4. **Mapping in Vim**
   Map the character sequence to page up in Vim config. In my case (using <kbd>\</kbd> as the first key), it will be `no <Bslash><C-h><Space> <C-b>`. If you need the mapping in visual mode too, also add `vno <Bslash><C-h><Space> <C-b>`.

I have used this settings for a while and it hasn't yet broken insert mode and replace mode of Vim as well as most
programs that accept text input on my system. But it's not a solution, but a workaround, which do have some flaws, e.g.:

- In Vim if you try to replace a character under the cursor  (by <kbd>r</kbd> by default) with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, you won't get a space.
- Some programs that interpret character sequences as commands like what Vim does may be affected.