# How to make shift+space shortcut go to end of line in vim?

Tags: vim

Normally when i use vscode I have a shortcut that uses shift+space that goes to the end of the line. Is there a way I could do this in vim.

Comment: In insert mode, use `<End>`, like in any text editor. In normal mode, use `$`. And consider going through `$ vimtutor` when you have 20-30 minutes free.

Comment: I thought it'd be a simple remapping in the .vimrc file, but it looks like it's not actually possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279959/how-can-i-make-shiftspacebar-page-up-in-vim

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift + A</kbd> moves to the end of the line and enters insert mode (i.e., **A**ppend to the line).

<kbd>$</kbd> just moves the cursor to the end of the line without entering insert mode.

You *could* possibly change <kbd>Shift + Space</kbd> or any other arbitrary key combination to do one of those things, but why not just use what Vim already has?

Comment: Agreed. And the `$` makes sense to use because also represents the end of a line in regular expressions. (Similar to how `^` moves to the first non-blank character in vim and represents the start of a line in regular expressions).